# как сделать чтобы рандомное число которое вывелось добавилось к переменной в discord py

Tags: discord.py

```
            a = await message.channel.send(random.choice(random_work) + str(random.randint(1, 200000)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменную `a` вы в данном случае каждый раз записываете объект только что отправленного сообщения. Не текст сообщения, а именно само сообщение, из которого вы можете получить текст `a.content`, канал, куда было отправлено сообщение `a.channel`, сервер `a.guild` и [**другую информацию**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message).

Это чтобы вам было понятно, что вообще означает переменная `a`.

---

Если же вы хотите создать переменную и прибавлять к ней каждое новое случайно значение, то для этого можно создать переменную `random_sum`, а затем в обработчике сообщений **генерировать случайное число**, затем **прибавлять** его к переменной, и после этого отправлять сообщение:

```
random_sum = 0

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global random_sum
    
    rand = random.randint(1, 200000)
    random_sum += rand
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(random_work) + str(rand))
```